# Is there a different way to declare an object in Javascript other than the below way?

Tags: javascript

I have seen this type of code in several of the javascript examples that I have been looking over at work. I think, but am not certain that the tempBall is supposed to be an object with properties, such as x, y, nextX, nextY, and so on.

Is there a more readable way that this could be done and have the code work the same. It just seems odd to me to declare a variable like

```
var tempBall;
```

and then start adding properties to the variable.

**Question: Can you just declare a var variable and then assign properties to it when ever, and is there a better practice to follow?**

code:

```
   var tempBall;

   tempBall = {x:tempX,y:tempY, nextX: tempX, nextY: tempY, radius:tempRadius, speed:tempSpeed, angle:tempAngle, velocityx:tempvelocityx, velocityy:tempvelocityy, mass:tempRadius};
```

Comment: You can declare javascript objects and properties statically as you have done or you can add properties at any time with code by just assigning a property/value to the object with `tempBall.whatever = "foo";`.  You can use both techniques.  Which to use depends upon the situation.  A single static declaration with multiple properties in it is generally considered better practice than adding each property with a separate line of code if that fits your situation.

Comment: You should look up variable hoisting in JavaScript in order to understand why the declaration and initialisation are often separated.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has two primary ways of assigning properties to objects after they are declared:

```
var tempBall = {};
// Explicitly named property
tempBall.foo = 'bar';
// Property name as a string
tempBall['foo'] = 'bar';

// You can also pass a variable rather than a static string
var key = 'foo';
tempBall[key] = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Question: Can you just declare a var variable and then assign properties to it when ever, and is there a better practice to follow?

I think what you might be referring to is something like this;

```
function dothings(){
  var anArray=[],
  i=0,
  j=0,
  ball,
  person;

  //... do some stuff

  person = { name: "..." };
  ball = { x: 0, y: 0 };

  // etc..
}
```

Why are all the **vars** declared at the beginning of the function instead of later when needed? (maybe this is what you are looking for)

If so, it is basically to save you from the headaches of variable hoisting as mentioned in the comments

- http://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-hoisting/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Also, Crockford says so. So it is convention. http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html see **Variable Declarations**

Answer (score -1):

In javascript you can just go:

```
 var tempBall = {x:tempX,y:tempY, nextX: tempX, nextY: tempY, radius:tempRadius, speed:tempSpeed, angle:tempAngle, velocityx:tempvelocityx, velocityy:tempvelocityy, mass:tempRadius};
```

The only time when you would declare the variable first and assign the values later would be to get if you need it for the scope of the variable.

Say I have a global variable tempBall and I want to set it's properties from within a function yet still keep it available globally:

```
var tempBall;

function someFuntion(someInput){
     tempBall = someInput;
}
```

Read more on javascript variable scope here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript can appear confusing when reading for the first time specially because it doesn't fix you into declaring the type of the a variable. The default value for any undeclared variable is undefined.

So, you could either do

```
var tempBall = {};

   tempBall = {x:tempX,y:tempY, nextX: tempX, nextY: tempY, radius:tempRadius, speed:tempSpeed, angle:tempAngle, velocityx:tempvelocityx, velocityy:tempvelocityy, mass:tempRadius};

tempBall.foo = 'bar';
```

or just

```
var tempBall = {x:tempX,y:tempY, nextX: tempX, nextY: tempY, radius:tempRadius, speed:tempSpeed, angle:tempAngle, velocityx:tempvelocityx, velocityy:tempvelocityy, mass:tempRadius};
```

but nothing is stopping you from doing this at the very next line, either:

```
tempBall = 'str';
```

Ofcourse, I'm not suggesting you do that :).